# Listview.count - InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index

Tags: c#, listviewitem

I have a problem with my listview item. hope you can help me with that.

my `listview.items.count` is not working properly. EventhoughI have 1 data, that suits my sql-string, (I checked it from db) count comes zero and i'm getting `"InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index" error.`

I dont know what i'm doing wrong? 
here's my code;

```
try
{
     mcon.Open();
     reader = comma.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
          int sira = listView1.Items.Count;
          listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("id"));
          listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("ad"));
          listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("soyad"));
          listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("evrakulastimi"));
          listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("basvurusonuclandimi"));
     }
}
catch
{                
}
```

Comment: item with index "listView1.Items.Count" never exist, you should  either address to "listView1.Items.Count - 1" item or add an item after int sira = listView1.Items.Count;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you've forgot to *add a new item*:

```
      while (reader.Read())
        {
            int sira = listView1.Items.Count;

            listView1.Items.Add("Put some text here"); // <- Add a new item

            listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("id"));
            listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("ad"));
            listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("soyad"));
            listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("evrakulastimi"));
            listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("basvurusonuclandimi"));
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Count actually gives you what it says, i.e. the count. Since listview.items collection is zero indexed, set `int sira = listView1.Items.Count-1;`

Comment: thank you for your time, but the "add" property solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :** You can Add Items to the `Listview` without using any `Index` parameter.

You need to assign first item `index` to `ListViewItem` and then add the `SubItems` .

Try This :

```
    ListViewItem lvi = listView1.Items.Add(reader.GetString("id"));
    lvi.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("ad"));
    lvi.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("soyad"));
    lvi.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("evrakulastimi"));
    lvi.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("basvurusonuclandimi"));
```